# CakePHP find with 'AND', 'OR' and 'NOW()::date'

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to translate this query in a find, but without success. My find doesnt return anything.

My SQL (in postgresql)

```
select * from projectversion where project='10003' releasedate>=now()::date or releasedate is null
```

MY FIND

```
   $projectversions = $this->find('list', array(
            'recursive' => -1,
            'fields' => array('vname'),
            'conditions' => array('project' => $id_project,'releasedate >=now()::date','OR'=>array('releasedate is null'))));
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original SELECT doesn't appear to be valid:

```
select * from projectversion where project='10003' releasedate>=now()::date or releasedate is null
```

Should it be:

```
select * from projectversion where project='10003' AND (releasedate>=now()::date or releasedate is null)
```

If so, your conditions should look like:

```
'conditions'=>array(
    'Model.project'=>10003,
    OR=>array(
        'Model.releasedate >= NOW()'
        'Model.releasedate IS NULL'
    )
)
```

produces:

```
WHERE Model.project = 10003 AND (Model.releasedate >= NOW() OR Model.releasedate IS NULL)
```